# "What any muscle or a group of muscles (do - does) is change energy to motion"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> What any muscle or a group of muscles (do - does) is change energy to motion.

For the above sentence, what is the right verb? "Do" or "does"?

Comment: Which one do you think is right? Why?

Comment: My question is this. Does the noun phrase "muscle or a group of muscles" as a subject takes "does" (singular verb) or "do" plural verb?

Comment: @asef I understand *[[a muscle] or [a group of muscles]]* and I understand *[any [[muscle] or [group of muscles]]]* but I don't understand *[[any muscle] or [a group of muscles]]*.

Answer (score 3):

The construction *A or B VERB* **can** be problematic if A and B differ in number—if one is singular and the other plural.<sup>†</sup> But in your case there is no problem: *of muscles* is a preposition phrase modifying *group*, and both of your subjects, *muscle* and *group*, are singular. Consequently, the verb is cast in the singular:

> A muscle changes energy to motion.
>   A group of muscles changes energy to motion.
>   A muscle or a group [of muscles] changes energy to motion.

---

<sup>†</sup> In conversation this is usually resolved by the verb agreeing in number with the closest subject:

> I'm not sure whether just John or both the Smiths have title to this property.
>   I'm not sure whether both the Smiths or just John has title to this property.

In writing, it may be resolved by rewriting:

> > I'm not sure whether just John has title to this property, or both the Smiths.

Comment: I think OP has screwed up the construction before he even *gets* to the verb. After all, **muscle** and **group of muscles** are both just singular nouns - no different to, say, **man** and **woman**. No-one would ever say *"What any man or **a** woman wants [is whatever the writer thinks they should want]"*. OP must either change **any** to **a**, or dump the **a** - either way, it then becomes clear only the singular verb form makes sense.